# In HBO's Chernobyl, how does Professor Ulana know Lyudmila was pregnant?

Tags: plot-explanation, chernobyl

When Professor Ulana Khomyuk visits the hospital in Moscow to talk to the plant workers, she sees Lyudmilla in her husband's room, inside the plastic, and inmediately goes nuclear (*pun intended*). When the nurse comes in, Professor Ulana Khomyuk asks her something like "How can you let a pregnant woman in here?".

The thing is, Lydmilla is pregnant but it is not visually evident yet, how can Ulana know? Was there some scene where they met before that was edited out of the final cut? Did I miss something?

Comment: If she knows who the firemen are, she likely knows their family situation etc. She's probably collected information. Not every minute detail needs to be shown.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I remember the shots correctly (I watched this last week, but it's possible that I have conflated or misinterpreted things):

Immediately before this scene, we see Lyudmilla tell Vasily (her husband) that they're going to have a baby, and we see her take his hand.  When Prof. Khomyuk looks through the window, we cut to a shot (from Prof. Khomyuk's POV) showing that Lyudmilla has placed Vasily's hand on her womb.  Prof. Khomyuk, seeing a young couple in such a pose, correctly interprets this gesture to mean that Lyudmilla is pregnant.

Comment: Didn't notice the hand, that would be it!

Answer (score 2):

The [show scripts](https://www.hbo.com/chernobyl/episode-scripts) have been released by the Executive Producer. It's very clear that the intention was for Khomyuk to see Lyudmilla with her hand on her stomach in the classic "*[holding her pregnant belly](https://www.shutterstock.com/search/pregnant-belly-hand-women)*" pose.

> REVEAL - she is right in front of the door into VASILY IGNATENKO'S room. She looks through the window.
>
> IN THE ROOM - Lyudmilla is sitting inside the protective plastic sheeting. She is saying something to her husband that we cannot hear. She touches him with her left hand. But **her right hand is held gently on her belly.**
>
> **She's smiling. Khomyuk stares in utter shock**, then BARGES INTO:
>
> INT. ISOLATION ROOM - CONTINUOUS She FLINGS the plastic slats aside and GRABS Lyudmilla by the wrist.
>
> **KHOMYUK:** *Get up!*
>
> <sub><sup>[Chernobyl: Episode 3](https://johnaugust.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Chernobyl_Episode-3Open-Wide-O-Earth.pdf)</sup></sub>

In the show it's Vasily who has his hand on her stomach, but the effect is largely the same in terms of story-telling.

> [image]

Comment: Glad to have confirmation that I had correctly remembered the gesture!

Comment: @MichaelSeifert - Aye. You're not wrong, but I always like to see evidence rather than assertion